# Is TDengine able to change replica number of a super(or chile table) table online?

Tags: database, tdengine

Is TDengine able to change replica number of a super(or chile table) table online? For example, change replica number from 3 to 5. Will the data be copied into new replica automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In tdengine you can change the number of replica using the follow command:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name REPLICA X;
```

The "x" represent the number of replica. However the X is an integer among[1,3], beside you also need to ensure the replica must less or equal to the number of dnodes.
Using the command below to check the num of dnode in tdengine.

```
show dnodes;
```